# Enthalpy but why "add work back in"? Why internal energy $U$ was not enough?

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry

The concept of Enthalpy has bugged me for quite some time. I just can't understand its meaning or reason for being.

- **Open|flow system enthalpy:**

  - I think I fully understand why **H** is used in flow systems! Below is my understanding of the usage and meaning of "flow H". So, please, don't waste time explaining it, unless you can somehow link flow system enthalpy and the one used in chemistry open beaker where reactions occur.
  - So, about the "flow enthalpy": You need to push some **mass** with internal energy $U$ into a control volume (c.v.), to do so you need to perform work **W=VdP** on the **c.v.**. Thus the thing you push in has U **and** VdP at the same time, so people use one letter for this sum **H**.   Now this is my guess: that since "flow H" just happens to have the same formula as people use in chemistry for enthalpy, so "flow people" started using the same name (IMHO).
- **Chemistry enthalpy:**

  - Using **H** in chemistry is beyond me, not the math part but the significance.
  - It looks like in chemistry we define the system in a completely different manner, otherwise, I can't explain "*adding **W** back in **U***". Alright, if in chemistry "*the system*" is defined" differently than in classical thermodynamics, why most books are silent on this topic.

[image: a usual definition of a system (control mass region in red) the weight is not the part of the system]
[image: an extended system definiton where the weight is a part of the system]

Usually in thermodynamics the system is defined as control mass of a gas (left picture above, red square). Now in thermochemistry there are some books which define what they call an "*extented system*" (right picture above, red rectangle) which consist not of gas alone but of gas **AND** the weight on top). In this "extended system" while isothermally heating gas, **W** escapes the gas but not the system because **W** goes into lifting the weight which is a part of the "*extented system*".

**So the questions are:**

1. Why in chemistry we use "extended system" (be it implicitly). Why the classical system is not enough anymore? What's so unique in chemical reactions that the classical system needed the "extension"? Why are books mostly silent on the topic of defining this extension **explicitly**. Why so shy, and never talk explicitly about the "new way to define the system"?
2. There is a line from French wiki on the Enthalpy. It goes like this:

> However, when a fluid undergoes phase changes (condensation, evaporation) or exothermic/endothermic chemical reactions (combustion, polymerization), the link between
> U, P, and V is lost during the transformation, so it is impossible to link their initial and final values. In addition, P and V are dependent variables that are often difficult (and not always useful) to separate.

Why in chemistry the system is defined as "the reactants"? No gas, no weight on top, nothing, only reactants. But still we somehow use P, V, T to work with the system, which in most cases has none of those parameters (solids do not have pressure, powders do not have volume, etc) But as I understand it, we still use the "ideal gas model aka the classical system" to measure the chemical system, but there is a catch... you need to add **PV**... I just don't get this thing. We study chemical systems but use math from ideal gas... WTF? But wait there is more... :) adding PV makes everything work?! :) I don't get it..

3. Is the problem chemical U+PV solving in measuring? I mean, I'm not a chemist and I might miss something so simple like problems with measuring of the reactions. Maybe the classical system (bomb calorimetr or open beaker calorimetr) is used as a kind of measuring device for a chemical system but the calssical system lacks smth and we add it back in in the from of PV... ?
4. Why sometimes Enthalpy is defined as

> Enthalpy (H) is the capacity to do non-mechanical work plus the capacity to release heat.

But chemical reactions can do mechanical work, they blow out and move things. I don't get this definition.
If enthalpy of reactants change making gas from solids, the work will be done by making room for the gas and thus it will be "*mechanical work done*" by "*the chemical system*".

Might this definition (capacity to do non-mechanical) is due to the fact that chemists do not care about mechanical work? Since they don't need one, they add it back in (thus extending the system (see above)) and wait for a time or think of the way to use this "W" in more chemical reactions, Thank God it is saved now in *the extended system* and not wasted on something stupid like "powering a pump or doing shaft work, or lifting a weight(wink, wink)" ... who needs mech work when you can make reactions, right!? Moar reactions! :)

> So let us, brother chemists, seal the W back inside the chemical
> system. How you ask me? And I answer: U+PV and no work shall escape
> out of this "new extended system", thus W will be forever sealed
> inside. And maybe later when gas shinks back into solid this W of the
> weight will give us some work back in the from of heat.

Comment: OMG.  There are about a zillion questions here.  Would it be possible for you to submit the key questions in separate threads so we can address them in bite-size chunks?  And can you please, in one of these, give an example of a "system" in comparison to an "extended system" using sketches?  Thank you.

Comment: Even if you are a chemist, you must be aware that, in industry, we have continuous flow chemical reactors, turbines, compressors, distillation columns, heat exchangers, etc. where we would be applying the open-system version of the first law of thermodynamics rather than the closed system version, right?

Comment: I'm not a chemist.  :( Maybe it's the reason for my mind-block. So, yeah, I know about columns, compressors etc. but what about them? How this knowledge should help me with chemical enthalpy while I think I understad the "open/flow system enthalpy"

Comment: @ChetMiller, Since I have no idea about the nature of my confusion and I can't define a border where it starts and ends, I decided to just dump all of it here in one go... Maybe someone will help me to figure out... I know the post is long but let's try it this way, if nothing good comes of it, I will change things. Thanks. Try answering any question you like, maybe others will join and answer the rest of them

Answer (score 1):

OK.  The editing you did was helpful.  Let's first talk about closed systems, which include the system in your left figure or the "extended" system in your right figure.

If you are going to use the closed system version of the first law of thermodynamics to analyze the change from an initial thermodynamic equilibrium state to a final thermodynamic equilibrium state, **then it is up to you to define and identify what you consider your "system;"** everything else is the surroundings.  This is totally a matter of your own personal choice.  However, be aware that some choices are easier to analyze thermodynamically.  Also, in all cases, it is important to also consider the use of the more complete version of the first law of thermodynamics, which can include potential energy and kinetic energy.  So, for a system in which changes in PE and KE are going to be significant, you would use $\Delta U+\Delta PE+\Delta KE=Q-W$, while, if changes in PE and KE are negligible, you can use $\Delta U=Q-W$. So, for the "extended" system on the right (which includes both the gas and the weight), $\Delta U+\Delta PE=Q$, where $\Delta U=$ is the change in internal energy of the gas, and $\Delta PE$ is the change in potential energy in the system $\Delta PE=mg\Delta h$.  For the system on the left (which includes only the gas), $\Delta U=Q-W$, where $W=mg\Delta h$ is the work done by the system on its surroundings.  You end up with the same results in both cases, independent of the choice of what you call your system.

Comment: This I understand. Why in chemistry they say: “the system is reactants” while implicitly use “extended system of a gas chamber”. Why implicit, why use extended and not classical system?

Comment: I don’t know their motivation for their choices.  As I said, the specification of the “system “ is your choice, depending on what seems easiest for you.

Comment: This part i understand, thanks. But what i need is to understand the motivation behind enthalpy

Comment: Unlike internal energy U and entropy S which are fundamental quantities, enthalpy H is not; all of thermodynamics could be derived without ever introducing the enthalpy H.  However, it also happens that the grouping U+PV occurs frequently in many types of thermodynamics problems.  For that reason, we introduce and define enthalpy H as shorthand for U+PV in thermodynamic equilibrium states.

Comment: I've found a good article on the abuse of H in flow systems context. You might like it. https://www.scirp.org/html/7-8302426_47908.htm Still, I'm confused as hell about the whole thing. And physics forum does not allow me to post (blocking for some reasone, yet I've never posted there before :(

Comment: I’ll look the paper over.  With regard to physics forums, please tell a little more.  Did it not let you join?  If so, what user name did you use?  If it did let you join, please start a conversation with me Chestermiller.

Comment: When I try to register I get "Your account has been rejected." I try to use my google account for this. nick name Coobit

Comment: I'm looking into it.

Comment: One response:  One issue that I see is that his chosen "Country Flag" does not match his IP addresses. And, "Got a veerrryyyy vague recollection of a real loser using that/similar handle."  So try matching your country flag to your IP address and/or choose a different user name.